# Is it possible to grow a div if it has relative position element?

Tags: html, css, css-position, autogrow

For every element inside a div it grows it's width , however when we placed a positioned element , here the error message is positioned to relative and has top of 3px. As it is showing container isn't growing. If I use

```
overflow: hidden; /* the message will be cut off */
```

How to fix this problem, am I missing any hacks. One way that I can do it growing it's height manually. However I think it isn't the most elegant solution, what if my content changes then I have re-calculate the height again.

[image: Auto grow container if it has a positioned element.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, thank you all for your help and support.

```
.invalid-msg {
   display: block;
   max-width:234px;
   margin-top:3px;
}
```